# ejabberd 20.12 SASL SCRAM modification

Tags: authentication, erlang, overriding, ejabberd, sasl-scram

I used to modify the ejabberd 17.x scram sasl in step 2 and step 4 in file `cyrsasl_scam.erl`.. and now with the new version of ejabberd the related file(s) has been moved to xmpp dependencies.

So my question is how do i modify the Step 2 and Step 4 in SCRAM authentication process ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically, the code from `src/cyrsasl_scram.erl` was moved to the file `deps/xmpp/src/xmpp_sasl_scram.erl`

So, apply your customizations in that file, then recompile everything (it will recompile only the changed files) with

```
./rebar compile
```

and then reinstall again ejabberd and the dependencies

```
make install
```